# how to add multiple permission in android?

Tags: android

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
```

I want to add permission one by one. I have 6 permission which require grants. I have seen so many app where more than one permission asks at a time. but i am not able to do it. it ask only for one time. i have added same code 5 times.

Comment: I wasted 2 hours for this. So people like me who is fresher in android will get easy idea on this.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS=0;
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,Manifest.permission.INTERNET,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
```

Comment: Is this the answer?, seems like the question before your edit?

Comment: @PetterFriberg because he realised he can't post a question with the answer in it so he most likely edited the question to be incorrect so that he could answer it(?). I think the idea behind that was to archive the solution for this problem in a way.